# runAction on multiple sequences

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

This is my code:

```
if (sprite != NULL)
{
    delay1 = CCDelayTime::create(1.5f);
    delay2 = CCDelayTime::create(3.0f);
    brickdelete = CallFunc::create([this]()
    {
        sprite->setOpacity(0);
        sprite->getPhysicsBody()->removeFromWorld();
    });
    brickcreate = CallFunc::create([this]()
    {
        sprite->setOpacity(255);
        sprite->setPhysicsBody(brickbody);
    });
    disintegratefunction = CallFunc::create([this]() {
        sprite->runAction(disintegrateAnim);
    });
    appearfunction = CallFunc::create([this]() {
        sprite->runAction(appearAnim);
    });
    runAction(Sequence::create(disintegratefunction, delay1, brickdelete, delay2, appearfunction, brickcreate, NULL));
}
```

I want to have multiple runAction instances happening at the same time. At the moment, if I start a runAction while another is in progress, I get multiple assertion fails and the remaining actions from the first sequence is added to the second runAction sequence (so the first body remains incomplete in some stage of the sequence).

I want them to be independent of each other. Is this possible? I also tried targetedaction but I’m not sure the code was good since it had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequence` will run one action after the other, to run actions at the same time you need to use `Spawn`.

> Spawn is very similar to Sequence, except that all actions will run at
>   the same time. You can have any number of Action objects and even
>   other Spawn objects!

So in your example:

```
if (sprite != NULL)
{
    delay1 = CCDelayTime::create(1.5f);
    delay2 = CCDelayTime::create(3.0f);
    brickdelete = CallFunc::create([this]()
    {
        sprite->setOpacity(0);
        sprite->getPhysicsBody()->removeFromWorld();
    });
    brickcreate = CallFunc::create([this]()
    {
        sprite->setOpacity(255);
        sprite->setPhysicsBody(brickbody);
    });
    disintegratefunction = CallFunc::create([this]() {
        sprite->runAction(disintegrateAnim);
    });
    appearfunction = CallFunc::create([this]() {
        sprite->runAction(appearAnim);
    });
    runAction(Spawn::create(disintegratefunction, delay1, brickdelete, delay2, appearfunction, brickcreate));
}
```

Ref: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/cocos2d-x/en/actions/sequences.html